# How often can my Application send APNS Notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I need to send remote APNS notifications from my server application to my iPhone applications. I want to know the frequency with which I can send remote APNS notifications in the following scenarios:

1. From my server application to the iPhone application on the same device.
2. From my server application to the iPhone applications on different devices.

I know that Apple has set some limit on this, but I do not know the limit.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As per my information Apple has not specified any specific limit but following text in programming guide of service.

> Apple Push Notification service continually monitors providers for irregular behavior, looking for sudden spikes of activity, rapid connect-disconnect cycles, and similar activity. Apple seeks to notify providers when it detects this behavior, and if the behavior continues, it may put the provider’s certificate on a revocation list and refuse further connections. Any continued irregular or problematic behavior may result in the termination of a provider's access to APNs.

Following paragraph is given [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1)

If you find any further details then post here......